# What is the meaning of the sample weight in scikit learn's MCC implementation?

Tags: metric, confusion-matrix

I wanted to use the [Matthews Correlation Coefficient](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.matthews_corrcoef.html) (MCC) measure of scikit learn to reduce the confusion-matrix to a single number and wondered what `sample_weight` stands for. Can someone explain how I correctly use this parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample weight is the weight that you want to give to your predictions. It can be useful in case you have some points that are more important than others, and you want that to reflect in your correlation coefficient.

Matthews Correlation Coefficient is computed as $$\frac{ TP \times TN - FP \times FN}{\sqrt{(TP + FP)(TP+FN)(TN + FP)(TN + FN)}}$$
where TP, TN, FP and FN are the number of True Positives, Negatives, etc. 
Normally, you would compute these as a simple count, but if you enter weights, then each of these become simply a weighted sum, where every point is considered for its assigned weight.